# file_get_contents adds newlines before the < character

Tags: php

I read code with file_get_contents:

```
$out = file_get_contents("https://somecode/");
print($out);
```

The code is supposed to be something like this:

```
var customToolTip = $.Link(
    {
        target: '-tooltip-<div class="faehnchen hidden-xs hidden-sm text-center"></div>',
        method: function (value) {
            $("#gebuehren_col_1").removeClass("color-success");
            $("#gebuehren_col_2").removeClass("color-success");
            $("#gebuehren_col_3").removeClass("color-success");
            var kosten = 2.25;
            if(value < 5000) {
                kosten += value * ((0.015/12)) * faktor;
                $("#gebuehren_col_1").addClass("color-success");
            } else if(value >= 5000 && value < 10000) {
                kosten += value * ((0.01/12)) * faktor;
                $("#gebuehren_col_2").addClass("color-success");
            } else if(value >= 10000) {
                kosten += value * ((0.005/12)) * faktor;
                $("#gebuehren_col_3").addClass("color-success");
            }
        }
    });
```

Instead the output is:

```
var customToolTip = $.Link(
    {
        target: '-tooltip-
<div class="faehnchen hidden-xs hidden-sm text-center"></div>
<p>',
        method: function (value) {
            $("#gebuehren_col_1").removeClass("color-success");
            $("#gebuehren_col_2").removeClass("color-success");
            $("#gebuehren_col_3").removeClass("color-success");
            var kosten = 2.25;
            if(value < 5000) {
                kosten += value * ((0.015/12)) * faktor;
                $("#gebuehren_col_1").addClass("color-success");
            } else if(value >= 5000 && value < 10000) {
                kosten += value * ((0.01/12)) * faktor;
                $("#gebuehren_col_2").addClass("color-success");
            } else if(value >= 10000) {
                kosten += value * ((0.005/12)) * faktor;
                $("#gebuehren_col_3").addClass("color-success");
            }
         }
    });
```

Do you have an idea, what might have cause this linebreak after

> target: '-tooltip-

or where the p tag to lines below comes from?

Comment: [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) definitely doesn't change the content it reads from the file, no matter if it is local or remote. How did you get the output you posted? From the browser?

Comment: ah okay good to know. yes this is the output of the browser